# StackOverflow logo broken download link

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, logo

I would like to download the StackOverflow logo in a vector file format. I found a download link for the logo in the EPS format at https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos, but it is 404'ing. As a matter of fact, all of the EPS files on that page are 404'ing, even though all of the PNG files are working fine.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is this intentional (i.e. does SO not want people to use the EPS format of their logo anymore?)?

Here is the broken link: https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.eps.

Comment: I suspect someone just overlooked updating it during the logo change a while back, highly doubt it's that they don't want the EPS version out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an artifact of an old build exclusion rule in place excluding *.eps files from the deployment robocopy. I just fixed the rule and the link will be back in the next build.

Comment: Thanks so much! All of the EPS links work perfectly now. You're the best!